# Use Session variable in html

Tags: asp.net, session

I get a session variable from a login form and then redirect to another page:

> ```
>     String a = Login1.UserName;
>     Session["user"] = a;
>     Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
> ```

In `Home.aspx` I wish to display in a div something like " `Hello -Session["user"]` " . How can I get the session var and use it in the html code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx) [block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0111sbh.aspx):

```
Hello <%:Session["user"]%>
```

Or if before .NET 4.0:

```
Hello <%=Server.HtmlEncode(Session["user"])%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was actually trying a lot to get my session value from a page to another html in `asp.net`.

However some syntactical error was always acting as an hindrance.

In order to solved it, I've created a web page and there I initiated the session in the code behind and directed that to the other page.

Note, this is a `.html` page, so now in the body I used

```
Hello <%=Session["UserID"]%>
```

instead of

```
Hello <%:Session["user"]%>
```

(which wasn't working) and it fetched the value from my `.cs` to my `.html` file.