# Is there any other way to use Session variable in cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, razor

I just readed answers from this question [Use Session variable in html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4533722/5603115), but this is not working for me. I tried `=` instead of `:` but same thing. I tried this also:

Hello <%Response.Write(Session("username"))%>

but nothing happens. I am using MVC pattern in ASP.NET application. I want to have format:

"Hello Username"

shown on the screen but instead of that I have

"Hello <%:Session["username"]%>".

This is my code in `.cs` file:

```
Session["username"] = user.Username;
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

This is my code in `.cshtml` file:

```
@if (Session["username"] != null)
{
    <li>
        Hello <%:Session["username"]%> 
    </li>
}
```

Any other idea?

Comment: `@Session["username"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<%` syntax is for old asp

for razor you can simply do `@Session["username"]`