# How to use public variable which used in whole ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to use public variable in Asp.NET with vb, in my web application i have class fils,aspx and asmx file, in this all pages i need access one public variable which i assign when user login, if i use session i cant access in asmx and class files, if i declare public variable in class file once page refresh it clear the assign values and became empty.

i want assign public variable with values and access in whole application until user logout, and once assign values when login it never change.

This is for connection sting , i know can declare in web conig, but we create each sql login for each and every user, so when user login we pass username to sql User ID

What I have tried:

For now i declare static variable and used in same page itself.If asp page no problem, but from class and asmx i need to each function connection strings.

Comment: Code is missing? Please provide a [mcve], thank you.

Comment: Using global variables in a multi-user application is always a _very_ bad idea.

Comment: If your application is currently stateless, I would not add session state just to store a connection string. That is madness. Compute the connection string each time you need it, using a template from web.config and filling it in with the user ID, which you can store in the forms auth cookie. The amount of processing required is nil compared to the processing required to maintain session state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use Session for this, it works:

1. in code-behind (classes) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178581(v=vs.140)
2. in aspx files - [Use Session variable in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533722/use-session-variable-in-html)
3. in ASMX web services - [Getting session in .NET ASMX web-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297637/getting-session-in-net-asmx-web-service) (thanks @AndrewMorton)